# Why do I get 'toUpperCase' of undefined when it's clearly defined?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

i'm hurting myself against a problem about string prototype method.

I want to create a method to camelCase any string.

Here is my currentcode :

```
String.prototype.camelCase=function(){
    let wordsArray = this.split(" ")
    wordsArray.forEach((word)=>{
      word[0] == word[0].toUpperCase()
    })
}
```

When i console.log(word[0].toUpperCase()) I get the first letter of each word in uppercase but when i try to apply the transformation to my "word" i get an error " Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined "

wtf ?

Comment: Does the string you're applying it to have a space at the start or end by any chance?

Comment: strings are immutable

Comment: nope no need to trim() :s

Comment: Give an example string that fails.

Comment: i'm not familiar with immutability, is there a workaround ?

Comment: build out a new string.

Comment: "actuel" en français = "current", not "actual" ;)

Comment: I think that the problem you have is that your string have space at the end or at start or more then one space if so you will have empty string and ''[0] is undefined. use `this.split(" ").filter(Boolean);`

Comment: `return str.replace(/\s(.)/g, x => x.toUpperCase())`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A way of working around the immutability of strings would be to just return a new string with the desired content like so:

```js
String.prototype.camelCase = function() {
    return this
        .split(" ")
        .map(w => {
          if (!w) return w
          return w[0].toUpperCase()+w.substring(1)
        })
        .join(' ')
}

console.log('hello world'.camelCase())
```